# Running code after Jupyter notebook finishes

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I would like to run code after the notebook finishes running (the code should run inside the same kernel)

I am familiar with registering callbacks on [IPython events](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/callbacks.html), but these only work at the cell level.

Is there anything similar at the notebook level? or maybe a way to detect that a cell is the last one?

Comment: Can you not just put some code at the end of the notebook?

Comment: @Brian61354270 - of course that is a "solution", but i am looking for a way to register a callback or similar.

Comment: How are you executing the notebook. Are you running it from the command line, using a library, or just running it in jupyer?

Comment: @JesseSealand - running in jupyter / using the `nbformat` package. if there is a method using other tools, they can still be helpful